# azure pricing api doesnt filter correctly

Tags: azure, rest, command-line-interface

I am unable to filter the prices returned from the azure cli:

```
az rest -u https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices --url-parameters '{"skuName":"F4s v2"}'
```

produces a clearly unfiltered result ending with:

```
    {
      "armRegionName": "westcentralus",
      "armSkuName": "Standard_E4ds_v5",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "effectiveStartDate": "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
      "isPrimaryMeterRegion": true,
      "location": "US West Central",
      "meterId": "00172462-4604-5a25-b1d4-f057577d68e0",
      "meterName": "E4ds v5 Low Priority",
      "productId": "DZH318Z096SL",
      "productName": "Virtual Machines Edsv5 Series Windows",
      "retailPrice": 0.212,
      "serviceFamily": "Compute",
      "serviceId": "DZH313Z7MMC8",
      "serviceName": "Virtual Machines",
      "skuId": "DZH318Z096SL/0424",
      "skuName": "E4ds v5 Low Priority",
      "tierMinimumUnits": 0.0,
      "type": "Consumption",
      "unitOfMeasure": "1 Hour",
      "unitPrice": 0.212
    }
  ],
  "NextPageLink": "https://prices.azure.com:443/api/retail/prices?skuName=F4s%20v2&$skip=100"
}
```

Although if i go to:

`https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?currencyCode=GBP&$filter=skuName%20eq%20%27F4s%20v2%27`

it pulls up the pricing info filtered no problem.

Can anyone explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you may follow to achieve the above requirement ,

*It seems there is an issue with the header as you have provide the parameter as the `skuname` so the pricings are not listed properly instead of that try to use `$filter`.*

You may use the below `api` format  for example   ;

```
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?currencyCode='EUR'&$filter=serviceFamily eq 'Compute'
```

You will get something like below;

[image]

For complete information please refer the below links:

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**|[***API endpoint for pricing details***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-endpoint) .
- **BLOG**| [***Filtering the Azure pricing API***](https://davecallan.com/azure-price-api-examples/) .